# Floating point types returned in ORM / DSL

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, floating-point, querydsl

[The Java™ Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) state that "this data type [double] should never be used for precise values, such as currency." Is the fact that an ORM / DSL is returning floating point numbers for database columns storing values to be used to calculate monetary amounts a problem? I'm using QueryDSL and I'm dealing with money. QueryDSL is returning a `Double` for any number with a precision up to 16 and a `BigDecimal` thereafter. This concerns me as I'm aware that floating point arithmetic isn't suitable for currency calculations.

From [this QueryDSL issue](https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/273) I'm led to believe that Hibernate does the same thing; see `OracleDialect`. Why does it use a `Double` rather than a `BigDecimal`? Is it safe to retrieve the `Double` and construct a `BigDecimal`, or is there a chance that a number with a precision of less than 16 could be incorrectly represented? Is it only when performing arithmetic operations that a `Double` can have floating-point issues, or are there values to which it cannot be accurately initialised?

Comment: Note that the code style is for code. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior about taglines, and http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting about formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be several concerns mentioned in the question, comments, and answers by [Robert Bain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3506000/robert-bain). I've collected and paraphrased some of these.

1. > Is it safe to use a double to store a precise value?

   Yes, provided the number of significant-digits (precision) is small enough.

   From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)

   > If a decimal string with at most 15 significant digits is converted to IEEE 754 double precision representation and then converted back to a string with the **same number of significant digits**, then the final string should match the original.

   - > But `new BigDecimal(1000.1d)` has the value 1000.1000000000000227373675443232059478759765625, why not 1000.1?

     In the quote above I added emphasis - when converted from a double the number of significant digits must be specified, e.g.

     `new BigDecimal(1000.1d, new MathContext(15))`
2. > Is it safe to use a double for arbitrary arithmetic on precise values?

   No, each intermediate value used in the calculation could introduce additional error.

Using a double to store exact values should be seen as an optimization. It introduces risk that if care is not taken, precision could be lost. Using a `BigDecimal` is much less likely to have unexpected consequences and should be your default choice.

3. > Is it correct that QueryDSL returns a double for precise value?

   It is not necessarily incorrect, but is probably not desirable. I would suggest you engage with the QueryDSL developers... but I see you have already raised [an issue](https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/1194) and they intend to change this behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Using floating point numbers for storing money is a [bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency) indeed. Floating points can approximate an operation result, but that's not what you want when dealing with money.

The easiest way to fix it, in a database portable way, is to simply store cents. This is the proffered way of dealing with currency operations in financial operations. Pay attention that most databases use the [half-away from zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_away_from_zero) rounding algorithm, so make sure that's appropriate in your context.

When it comes to money you should always ask a local accountant, especially for the rounding part. Better safe then sorry.

Now back to your questions:

1. > Is it safe to retrieve the Double and construct a BigDecimal, or is
   >   there a chance that a number with a precision of less than 16 could be
   >   incorrectly represented?

   This is a safe operation as long as your database uses at most a 16 digit precision. If it uses a higher precision, you'd need to override the OracleDialect and
2. > Is it only when performing arithmetic operations that a Double can
   >   have floating-point issues, or are there values to which it cannot be
   >   accurately initialised?

   When performing arithmetic operations you must always take into consideration the monetary rounding anyway, and that applies to `BigDecimal` as well. So if you can guarantee that the database value doesn't loose any decimal when being cast to a java Double, you are fine to create a `BigDecimal` from it. Using `BigDecimal` pays off when applying arithmetic operations to the database loaded value.

As for the threshold of 16, according to [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format):

> The 11 bit width of the exponent allows the representation of numbers
>   with a decimal exponent between 10−308 and 10308, with full 15–17
>   decimal digits precision. By compromising precision, subnormal
>   representation allows values smaller than 10−323.

Comment: Thanks for your input, Vlad. The situation I'm in, is that I'm pulling a 5 decimal place fund price from a third party database. Funds have a price each day and individuals own a number of units of that fund, so in this case, I'm afraid that storing the cents (or pennies where I am) isn't something that would help matters. I'll edit the question to make this clear.

Comment: Thanks Vlad. Why is representing a number as a `double` safe up to 16 digit precision? What is it that makes the 16 digit precision the threshold? I was curious about this, as the Hibernate implementation specifically switches to `BigDecimal` as the precision exceeds 16.

Comment: Based on your answer to my question about the 16 decimal digit precision threshold, can you explain the value of `BigDecimal foo = new BigDecimal(1000.1d)` mentioned in my answer, which appears to contradict your assertion that "This is a safe operation as long as your database uses at most a 16 digit precision". Thanks, Rob.

Comment: But you will never get absolute precision and that's why rounding is so important. You can easily get a non fixed decimal result during a division anyway. So, if an accountant doesn't use a 16 digits precision, are you absolutely sure you need it?

Comment: So, you always have to round to cents. No matter how many calculations you do, in the end you have to round to cents, because you can't have 15$ and 24,67 cents. You have 15$ and 24 or 25 cents, depending on the rounding method your financial operations require.

Comment: You will get absolutely precision when representing a decimal number as a `BigDecimal`, whilst you won't when representing it as a floating point number. As you can see from my example, it's not even making it to 16 decimal digit precision, that's 14 from one specific example. As the number on the left hand side get larger, the precision gets lower. `new BigDecimal(100000000000000.1d)` gives you 100000000000000.09375.

Comment: Try it with new BigDecimal("1000.1") instead.

Comment: Obviously it will work with a `String` but if you have a `Double`, that doesn't help. Calling `toString()` on a `Double` gives you a printable representation that isn't the same as the exact value that the `Double` represents. See the `toString()` documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html.

Comment: Right. But you can't escape the fact that you represent money as double. The only solution is to round to double digits and then you should be fine.

Comment: Vlad, yes I can - it's not stored as a floating point number in the database and using the correct JDBC mapping and `BigDecimal` it's never stored as a floating point in Java.

Answer (score 1):

After much deliberation, I must conclude that the answer to my own question:

> Is the fact that an ORM / DSL is returning floating point numbers for database columns storing values to be used to calculate monetary amounts a problem?

put simply, is yes. Please read on.

> Is it safe to retrieve the Double and construct a BigDecimal, or is there a chance that a number with a precision of less than 16 could be incorrectly represented?

A number with a precision of less than 16 decimal digits is incorrectly represented in the following example.

```
BigDecimal foo = new BigDecimal(1000.1d);
```

The `BigDecimal` value of `foo` is 1000.1000000000000227373675443232059478759765625. 1000.1 has a precision of 1 and is being misrepresented from precision 14 of the `BigDecimal` value.

> Is it only when performing arithmetic operations that a Double can have floating-point issues, or are there values to which it cannot be accurately initialised?

As per the example above, there are values to which it cannot be accurately initialised. As [The Java™ Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) clearly states, "This data type [float / double] should never be used for precise values, such as currency. For that, you will need to use the java.math.BigDecimal class instead."

Interestingly, calling `BigDecimal.valueOf(someDouble)` appeared at first to magically resolve things but upon realising that it calls `Double.toString()` then reading [`Double`'s documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) it became apparent that this is not appropriate for exact values either.

In conclusion, when dealing with exact values, floating point numbers are never appropriate. As such, in my mind, ORMs / DSLs should be mapping to `BigDecimal` unless otherwise specified, given that most database use will involve the calculation of exact values.

**Update:**

Based on this conclusion, I've raised [this issue](https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/1194) with QueryDSL.

Answer (score 0):

It is not only about arithmetic operations, but also about pure read&write.
Oracle `NUMBER` and `BigDecimal` do both use decadic base. So when you read number from database and then you store it back you can be sure, that the same number was written. (Unless it exceeds Oracle's limit of 38 digits).

If you convert `NUMBER` into binary base (`Double`) and then you convert it back do decadic then you might expect problems. And also this operation must be much slower.